# Почему Unity собирая проект для iOS не добавляет общий файл проекта Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace

Tags: unity3d, xcode

У меня в проекте Unity есть несколько библиотек AdMob Firebase поэтому мне надо дополнительные библиотеки cocoa pods когда я собираю билд для Xcode. Когда я первый раз собираю проект то все хорошо появляется вот такой вот файлик Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace я его жму и захожу в Xcode и все хорошо, но когда я 2, 3, 4 раз собираю то этого файла Unity не создает, почему как мне его создать? Вообще я знаю что могу установить через консоль cocoapods, и этот файл проекта появиться,  но тогда при запуске я почти всегда получал какие то ошибки. Unity все правильно собирает но почему во второй раз не хочет не пойму

Comment: Если unity видит в указанной директории соответствующий проект xcode, то появляется диалоговое окно с вопросом создавать ли заново или обновить имеющийся. При обновлении заменяются только файлы unity, даже настройки проекта в plist больше не обновляются, даже если были изменены.

Comment: Спасибо полезная для меня информация, учту. Но надо удалить вопрос, я был невнимательным unity вообще не собирал проект под mac выбрасывал ошибку поэтому и не было Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace